# UWP - Zoom Image and scrollbar

Tags: image, xaml, uwp, scrollview, zooming

I have write a simple code in XAML for zoom an Image

```
    <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="Griglia_Immagine">

        <ScrollViewer  Name="MyScrollViewer" MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <Image Name="Imm_Visualizzata"   Source="Assets/Test.jpg" >

        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
```

When i zoom the image it became more big.
On my right i can see the vertical scrool bar  but i don't see the Horizontal one.
So... where the image is big i can move Up-Down ...but  if i move left-right the image where i leave my finger the image return on left border.

I'had tried to set  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility ...
If i set both to Hidden the start image is very big  (original format) If i set both to Disabled  the zoom not work.

If i set One on Hidden and one on Disabled  the zomm work but i can move the image only  vertival or horizontal... where i had set the Hidden value..

Anyone had solved it ?
Thanks

Comment: I could not understand your question. If I set ScrollViewer like this `<ScrollViewer  Name="MyScrollViewer" MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">` The zoom works well. I can move the image both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: If i set the controls like you had written the image zoom but at the start it is rendereng at the original format, more large that my screen.
I  would like to view the image, at the start big then my image control in the grid

Comment: You could resize that image. E.g, set width and height

Comment: OK...but How can i set Height and Width of my  Image Control ?
My ScrollViewer Control haven't these value. And mu Grid Row is set to '*'

Comment: Try this `<ScrollViewer  Name="MyScrollViewer"  MinZoomFactor="1" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <Image Name="Imm_Visualizzata"   Source="Assets/Test.jpg" Height="200" Width="300"/>
            </ScrollViewer>`

Comment: In this way is ok !!!   but my Image control can be without set value for arrange to the maximum of the free space